# how to go through images in a for loop in order

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have about 13000 images that need to be run through a python script in a particular order. I tried using a for loop, however, it doesnt go through the images in the correct order. The folder containing these images are in order but not necessarily by name. I have a csv file containing the file names in order. Perhaps it could read the csv file to find which one to iterate?

Im trying to classify multiple images and then print them to a csv using tensorflow, python, a retrained graph, and their respective labels produced prior to this.

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys
import csv
import numpy
import os

files_dir = os.getcwd() + '/Desktop/model/test_stg1/'
files = os.listdir(files_dir)

for f in files:
    if f.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
        image_path = files_dir + '/' + f


        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()


        label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                       in tf.gfile.GFile("/home/fly/Desktop/model/retrained_labels.txt")]


        with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/home/fly/Desktop/model/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

        with tf.Session() as sess:

            softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

            predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                                   {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})


            top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]


            text_file = open("Outputtest2.csv", "a")
            for node_id in top_k:
                human_string = label_lines[node_id]
                score = predictions[0][node_id]
                print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
                text_file.write('%s (%.5f),' % (human_string, score))
```

Comment: Can you do `files = sorted(files)`?

Comment: What is your question? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Comment: Hi @Craig No need, as you can see, Pablo already answered this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the list of files in a CSV sorted the way you want, you can open the CSV[1] and use that to iterate through your files. For example:

```
with open('files_data_sorted.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    filedatareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in filedatareader:
        # let's suppose the filename is in column 0
        fname = row[0]
        image_path = files_dir + '/' + fname
        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
```

Or, if you have your files sorted alphabetically, you can simply run `files.sort()`

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html